# How to upload multiple files in dropbox using java

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have created a java cucumber maven project. Now I want to push all report in dropbox once execution of test script is done.

My main goal is to push report folder on Dropbox.

I am using below maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I know it's old dependency but code provided by Dropbox is only supported by this lib. Later version is showing errors or deprecated methods.

Source:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java

Code I am using is as below:

```
public class DropBoxUpload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
        // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
        final String APP_KEY = "MyAppKey";
        final String APP_SECRET = "MyAppSecretKey";

        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
            Locale.getDefault().toString());
        DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

        // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
        String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
        System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
        System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
        System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");

        String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

        // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
        DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
        String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;

        DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);

        System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

        File inputFile = new File("working-draft.txt");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        try {
            DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
                DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("D:\\MavenJenkinsCI\\target\\cucumber-html-reports");
        System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("magnum-opus.txt");
        try {
            DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null,
                outputStream);
            System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I am running this code. It stuck on below line:

```
   String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();
```

Any idea why?

Environment

- Window 10
- Java 8

If you have any workaround please share.

It will really help.

Comment: What do you mean by _It stuck on below line_ ? It throws any kind of Exception?

Comment: nup no exception it throws. Just it stuck their with no result. so everytime I force close the execution after 10-15 min

Comment: The old version of the SDK you're trying to use is for Dropbox API v1, which is now retired. You should use the new version: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java There's an uploading example here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java

Comment: @Greg - thanks a lot Greg .. I was actually looking something like same .... You can post it as answer ... I will  implement it , currently I m out of office.. will let you know regarding same ...

Comment: @Greg - It's working thanks :) .. For future ref of other problem seekers .. This article also helps me .. http://blog.camilolopes.com.br/tag/dropbox-token/

Comment: Hi @Greg and Anastasios - I am facing similer kinda issue for google drive API.. please look into it if possible. I have posted the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156473/how-to-upload-zip-file-on-google-drive-getting-error-like-insufficient-permi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg has provided correct dependencies and example which leads me to accomplish by requirements.

The new version:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java

There's an uploading example here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java

I also add an article below which helps me during the integration :

http://blog.camilolopes.com.br/tag/dropbox-token/

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it stuck on that line is normal. The program just expects the user's input from the console in order to proceed to the next line of code.